# How to hit an API in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm testing front end using Selenium IDE, and I want to hit some api to generate test data such as Test Email address and password, before actually starting test.

I want to first hit API and store it's response into some variable which I can use it later in UI flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution like this:-

Use command "Execute Script" to execute Javascript code under currently opened Browser window. Here is what documentation says:

> Executes a snippet of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment will be executed as the body of an anonymous function. To store the return value, use the 'return' keyword and provide a variable name in the value input field.
>
> Arguments:
>
> script - The JavaScript snippet to run.
>
> variable name - The name of a variable without brackets."

Hence, in order to hit some api, we can write code like this:-

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open('GET', 'https://google.com', false); 
request.send(null); 
return request.responseText;
```